# Single domain with Apache https as a proxy for many local servers

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

Using Apache we need to setup number of instances of our application running on different servers internally in such a way that they are visible under our single domain name externally.
This is so they were available over SSL using single certificate.

Internally we have:

```
http://srv1:8021/theapp
http://srv2:8022/theapp
```

Externally we like to enable these as:

```
https://www.domain.com/test1
https://www.domain.com/test2
```

Additional issue is caused by our path "/theapp". This is hardcoded and application will only work with this as the root path. (Unfortunately it seems to be harcoded in the frontend as well.)

So after initial request to `https://www.domain.com/test1` I need Apache to translate on the fly all further requests and responses in such a way that end user sees `https://www.domain.com/theapp` in both cases. 
It would be maybe simpler if we had:

```
https://test1.domain.com/theapp
https://test2.domain.com/theapp
```

but in such case we probably would need many SSL certs.

What is the correct Apache configuration for such case?

Comment: @Dawud Honestly, I have not tried anything. I could not find clear explanation of the configuration that would work for this case. And most of all I want to know what is CORRECT configuration.

Comment: Well, you need to try _something_, otherwise you leave no option other than pointing you to the [Apache online documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/).